# Unable to reverse item in an option selector

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am trying to reverse the order of the options in a input selector using Javascript. Currently it's printed from 1 to 10. I am trying to make it appear form 10 to 1. Here's the code I added:

```
<select class="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>

let arr=document.getElementsByClassName("multiple");
arr.reverse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just call `reverse()` on a javascript array and expect it to change DOM structure. That method does not alter the DOM elements by just calling it like that.

Here is one way of reversing options in a SELECT element:

```js
// get a reference of the select element
let select=document.querySelector("select.multiple");
// get a reference to all child options
let options = document.querySelectorAll("select.multiple option");

// prepare an empty array to hold all values in options
let arr = [];

// loop through each option and add its value to the array
options.forEach(opt => {
  arr.push(opt.innerText);
});

// clear all existing options in the select parent
select.innerHTML = "";

// loop through the array in reverse order
for(let i=arr.length-1; i>=0;i--) {

  // create an OPTION element and assign its value
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  option.innerText = arr[i];

  // append that OPTION to the parent SELECT element
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<select class="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it into an array so you can `.reverse()` the array, but then you'll also need to re-append the elements in the new order so as to rearrange them in the actual DOM:

```
const multiple = document.querySelector('.multiple');
for (const child of [...multiple.children].reverse()) {
  multiple.appendChild(child);
}
```

```js
const multiple = document.querySelector('.multiple');
for (const child of [...multiple.children].reverse()) {
  multiple.appendChild(child);
}
```

```html
<select class="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
```

Or insert the elements in their original order, but at the top instead of the bottom of the parent:

```
const multiple = document.querySelector('.multiple');
for (const child of multiple.children) {
  multiple.insertBefore(child, multiple.children[0]);
}
```

```js
const multiple = document.querySelector('.multiple');
for (const child of multiple.children) {
  multiple.insertBefore(child, multiple.children[0]);
}
```

```html
<select class="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call a function which reverses the option list like this.

```js
(function reverseDD(e)
{
  for(var i=e.options.length-2;i>=0;i--)
  {
    e.appendChild(e.options[i]);
  }
})(document.getElementsByClassName('multiple')[0])
```

```html
<select class="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
```